# how to get value of selected cell in grid view in c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am working on datagridview in c#, I add a data set to the gridview from database and I added a button column in that datagrid view, I want to get the value of the cells of the row when i click on button

Comment: WC to SO can you please share some code with us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
yourGridName.Rows[index].Cells["columnName"].Text
```